# exclude an account from scrappng tweet with python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to scrape a tweet from Twitter with a keyword in the form of the name of an internet service provider, but I want to exclude the customer service account from that internet service provider.
What should I add in my code?

```
consumer_key = 'xxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

csvpefile = open ('test1.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvpefile)


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q=["telkomsel"], 
                           count=6000, 
                           lang="id",
                           since="2020-09-23",
                           tweet_mode = 'extended', 
                           trucated='false').items(6000):

    
    tweettext = str(tweet.full_text.lower().encode('ascii',errors='ignore'))
    if tweettext.startswith("rt @") == False and hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status') == False:
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.user.id, tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
        print(tweet.user.id, tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.full_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `q=["telkomsel -from:telkomsel"]`

This should find references to that account but exclude Tweets sent from that account.